# Spring Data MongoDB logging mongoTemplate query

Tags: mongodb, logging, spring-data-mongodb

I want to see the native `mongodb` query created by `Spring Data`.

I tried the following.

1. Created `application.properties` file under `META-INF/resources` and added the following

   ```
   logging.level.org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate=DEBUG
   ```
2. Created `log4j.properties` file under `META-INF/resources` and added the following

   ```
   log4j.category.org.springframework.data.document.mongodb=DEBUG
   log4j.category.org.springframework.data.document.mongodb=DEBUG
   log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %40.40c:%4L - %m%n
   ```
3. In my code level

   ```
   import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
   import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

   ...

   private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(abc.class);

   ...
   log.info(mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, xyz.class, xyz.class));
   ```

I am not able to find any query in my jetty console. Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: do you have the necessary dependencies in your classpath. for example log4j